# Specify default value for a logback property, in spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

In `spring-boot` application, I am trying to config a default dir for `logback`.

Usually, in `logback.xml` I would config it this way:

```
<property name="logFile.dir" value="${catalina.home:-/tmp}/logs" />
```

The separator is `:-`.

But, in `application.properties`:

I have to config it this way:

```
logging.file=${catalina.home:/tmp}/logs/sportslight.log
```

Need to change the separator from `:-` to `:`.

The questions are:

- In `logback.xml`, which is the correct separator, `:-` or `:`?
- In `application.properties`, why only `:` works, is it because spring-boot would handle it first before pass the value to logback?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In logback.xml the correct separator is `:-`. More details in [the logback docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#defaultValuesForVariables).

In Spring the correct separator is `:` since Spring supports the `${my.property:defaultValue}` syntax. More details in [the PlaceholderConfigurerSupport doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.html).

So, when faced with a choice of default value separator for variable substitution the logback author(s) chose `:-` and the Spring author(s) chose `:`.

Answer (score 5):

In logback.xml or logback-spring.xml, you can set default value for both **system property** and **project property** (or you can say spring property).

1) For system property, you can simply go with the `:-` syntax. In the following example,  the default level of `ThresholdFilter` is `ERROR`.

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>${sentryLevel:-ERROR}</level>
    </filter>
  </appender>

</configuration>
```

You can override it by starting the java process with, such as `-DsentryLevel=INFO`.

2) For project property/spring property, you can set `defaultValue` in the `springProperty` element.

```
<configuration>

  <springProperty scope="context" name="sentryLevel" source="your.prop.path" defaultValue="ERROR"/>

  <appender name="sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>${sentryLevel}</level>
    </filter>
  </appender>

</configuration>
```

You can override it by changing the application.properties or application.yml.

```
your.prop.path=INFO
```